# Throw away whole array but the first item

Tags: php

Assume I have the following array:

```
$array(
  '32' => array('name' => 'paul', 'age' => 43),
  '17' => array('name' => 'eric', 'age' => 19),
  '99' => array('name' => 'dave', 'age' => 65)
)
```

I am only interested in the first `$array` item:

```
$array2 = array('key'=> 32, 'name' => 'paul', 'age' => 43)
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this? In other words, can I throw out all other items of $array with one command?

Comment: Do you want your first element to be extended with the `key`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use **[`array_shift()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)**.

> `array_shift()` shifts the first value of the array off and returns it,
>   shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. All
>   numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero
>   while literal keys won't be touched.

```
$array2 = array_shift($array);
```

This means that `$array2` now holds the first element, while `$array` holds the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 $array2 = array_shift($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArr = reset($array);
```

I think there is no problem with that.

Comment: That would produce an array that holds another array with a key of zero.  Just doing `$newArr = reset($array);` would be more what the OP is looking for I think (minus the `key` key).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options, really. Either you can just select the first item in the array

```
$array2 = $array[0];
```

Or you could use array_slice as

```
$array2 = array_slice($array, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`reset`ting an array also returns the first element (`end()` returns the last):

```
$first = reset( $array );
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

But to generate the exact result you want, you could write something like this

```
foreach( $array as $k => $first ){ // get first sub-array and its key
  $first['key'] = $k; // add the key
  break;              // we don't care about the other elements, goodbye
}
```

Futuregeek's method fixed:

```
$first =

  // returns first element, and sets it as the current element for key()
  reset( $array )

  // instead of array_merge, (sometimes) you can use the + operator
  +

  // key() will return the appropriate key after reset()
  array('key' => key( $array ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Array_shift is probably the best way. But just for fun here is another way.

```
$first_element = end(array_reverse($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$k = array_merge(array('key' => key($array)), array_shift($array));
```

Returns in the specified format.

[key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) gets you the first key, [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) gets you the first value, and merge using [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge)

Comment: Shorter + resets the array: `$k = reset($array) + array('key' => key($array));` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try It : 


$arr = array(
  '32' => array('name' => 'paul', 'age' => 43),
  '17' => array('name' => 'eric', 'age' => 19),
  '99' => array('name' => 'dave', 'age' => 65)
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    $result[$key] = $value;
    break;
}
print_r($result);

##-------Secount Way If you don't want Key 32--------------------------

$arr = array(
  '32' => array('name' => 'paul', 'age' => 43),
  '17' => array('name' => 'eric', 'age' => 19),
  '99' => array('name' => 'dave', 'age' => 65)
);

$arr = array_reverse($arr);
print_r(end($arr));

#------ Third Way If you don't want  Key 32 -------------

echo "<br>=======<br>";

$arr = array(
  '32' => array('name' => 'paul', 'age' => 43),
  '17' => array('name' => 'eric', 'age' => 19),
  '99' => array('name' => 'dave', 'age' => 65)
);

$array2 = array_shift($arr);
print_r($array2);
```

Comment: The opposite of `end` is `reset`, you don't have to reverse the array! See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php